# Searching a vector of object pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a Player class where each object of the type Class has a name, wins, losses, and draws.  Each object of the Player class is created by calling the_player = new Player(the_name).  When the user inputs a new name to add a Player object to the program a pointer is pushed into a vector AllPlayers.  The program should check before pushing the new pointer that the desired player does not already exist in said vector.  I have to do this check several times throughout my program so I thought I'd write a function for it.  Here is my function:

```
int findPlayer(vector<Player*> &vals, string name_in)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++){
        if (vals[i]->getName() == name_in){
            cout << vals[i]->toString() << endl;
            return i;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
};
```

When the option is requested to add a new Player the following code is used:

```
do {
    cout << "Name: "; 
    cin >> the_name;

    if (findPlayer(AllPlayers, the_name) != -1){
        cerr << "Player already exists\n";
    }
} while (findPlayer(AllPlayers, the_name) != -1);

the_player = new Player(the_name);
AllPlayers.push_back(the_player);
```

For some reason, though, every time I try to add a new player it throws "Player already exists" and never leaves the do-while loop.  This is even true when the AllPlayers vector is empty.  I added a cout << findPlayer(AllPlayers, the_name) for debugging and it printed 4192252 which I assume is the largest element possible in a vector.

So the question is: Why does it return 4192252 rather than -1?

Comment: Did you enable the compiler warnings? Mine warns about the bug that causes this.

Comment: Did you step through your code with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find player function should be something like:

```
int findPlayer(vector<Player*> &vals, string name_in)
{
    if(vals.size() == 0)
        return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++){
        if (vals[i]->getName() == name_in){
            cout << vals[i]->toString() << endl;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

Comment: This solves the question to exactly 0%. You return -1, which still prints out an error.

Comment: @Blacktempel: Only if it's not found; if it is, `return i` returns some other value. This is correct, although the initial test is pointless.

Comment: This solved it.  Giving it the base case that there isn't anything in the vector threw -1, which would mean that the indicated Name is not found in the vector, which would be correct.

Answer (score 4):

If `vals` is empty then the for loop is never entered and the function exits without hitting a return statement. Meaning that you get a random value returned instead, in this case `4192252` happens to be in the return register. Your compiler warnings will have told you this if you read them.

Comment: I'm on Visual Studio 2013.  I have to assume warnings are enabled cause I get lots of warnings all the time (new to C++), but nothing was displayed on this one.

Comment: @Spencer You will have seen [this warning (C4715)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6deaf4k9.aspx) which is a level 1 warning and therefore should be visible at all warning levels. You should start compiling with `/WX` to treat warnings as errors if you want to have the compiler help you find silly things like this.

Answer (score 3):

What you think, what will be returned from findPlayer if vals is empty?

Is it defined?

Comment: Even though it points straight at the answer, this should be a comment. Add an explanation for an upvote.

Comment: I have no reputation to put comments. I must have 50. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the vector is empty, you don't enter the loop at all, so don't reach a `return` statement and don't return a valid value. You should enable compiler warnings to catch this error.

Otherwise, you only check the first item, and return immediately whether or not it matched. You want to return if you find a match, but keep looking otherwise, and only return -1 if there is no match:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vals.size(); i++){
    if (vals[i]->getName() == name_in){
        cout << vals[i]->toString() << endl;
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the function the following way

```
bool findPlayer( const std::vector<Player*> &vals, const std::string &name_in )
{
    std::vector<Player*>::size_tyoe i = 0;

    while ( i < vals.size() && vals[i]->getName() != name_in ) ++i;

    return i != vals.size();
}
```

Take into account that member function `getName` has to be defined with qualifier `const`.

As for your function then it returns nothing in case when the vector is empty or returns -1 in case when the first element of the vector does not coincide with the string.

Take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::find_if` declared in header `<algorithm>` that can be used instead of your function.